Resources to understand problems posed to Newtonian mechanics by Maxwell equations
Einstein undertook writing his paper on special relativity in response to the 'crisis' that emerged in physics when trying to do mechanics for fast-moving bodies in the light (pun intended) of Maxwell's equations that gave rise to some weird problems with Newtonian mechanics.
Could you please recommend a good book or book chapter that covers every detail of this 'crisis' and explains it lucidly at an undergraduate level?

Is there any reason why 'crisis' has to be in all-capitals?

Zahar gives a very detailed account in Why Did Einstein's Programme Supersede Lorentz's? parts I and II. Another source is Miller, Frontiers of Physics: 1900–1911.
